# Match two columns in Excel file and get other column values - Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two Excel files, say, **wb1.xlsx** and **wb2.xlsx**.

wb1.xlsx

```
adsl    svc_no    port_stat    adsl.1    Comparison result
2/17
2/24
2/27
2/33
2/37
3/12
```

wb2.xlsx

```
caller_id    status    adsl    Comparison result
n/a          SP        2/37    Not Match
n/a          RE        2/24    Not Match
n/a          SP        2/27    Match
n/a          SP        2/33    Not Match
n/a          SP        2/17    Match
```

What I want to do is match the adsl of **wb2.xlsx** to **wb1.xlsx** and get the other values to the other columns.

My expected output is to update **wb1.xlsx** with the values from **wb2.xlsx**

```
adsl    svc_no    port_stat    adsl.1    Comparison result
2/17    n/a       SP           2/17      Match
2/24    n/a       RE           2/24      Not Match
2/27    n/a       SP           2/27      Match
2/33    n/a       SP           2/33      Not Match
2/37    n/a       SP           2/37      Not Match
3/12
```

Upon searching, I was able to check that `pd.merge()` is able to do the matching.

I tried it this way:

```
result = pd.merge(df2, pri_df, on=['adsl', 'adsl'])
```

Unfortunately, it creates new columns and do not update the existing. Also, it only gets the values that it was able to matched and disregard the other rows.

I also tried to get the indices of the columns in **wb2.xlsx** and assigned it to the columns **wb1.xlsx** but it just copied it literally.

Any reference that would help will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin` function of pandas:

```
result = df2.loc[df2['adsl'].isin(pri_df['adsl'])]
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I see, it matches the dataframes from two Excel files. How do you suggest I will get the values from **wb2.xlsx** and update it to **wb1.xlsx**?

Comment: You can create a new excel file instead of updating the same. and then dump the previous one.

Comment: Yes, that will be more likely to happen, although how will I be able to bring the other columns of **wb2.xlsx** to new excel file?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
print (df1)
   adsl  svc_no  port_stat  adsl.1  Comparison result
0  2/17     NaN        NaN     NaN                NaN
1  2/24     NaN        NaN     NaN                NaN
2  2/27     NaN        NaN     NaN                NaN
3  2/33     NaN        NaN     NaN                NaN
4  2/37     NaN        NaN     NaN                NaN
5  3/12     NaN        NaN     NaN                NaN

print (df2)
   caller_id port_stat  adsl Comparison result
0        NaN        SP  2/37         Not Match
1        NaN        RE  2/24         Not Match
2        NaN        SP  2/27             Match
3        NaN        SP  2/33         Not Match
4        NaN        SP  2/17             Match
```

---

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'status':'port_stat'})
d = {'adsl.1': lambda x: x['adsl']}
df2 = df2.assign(**d)
print (df2)
   caller_id port_stat  adsl Comparison result adsl.1
0        NaN        SP  2/37         Not Match   2/37
1        NaN        RE  2/24         Not Match   2/24
2        NaN        SP  2/27             Match   2/27
3        NaN        SP  2/33         Not Match   2/33
4        NaN        SP  2/17             Match   2/17

df22 = df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)]
print (df22)
  port_stat  adsl Comparison result adsl.1
0        SP  2/37         Not Match   2/37
1        RE  2/24         Not Match   2/24
2        SP  2/27             Match   2/27
3        SP  2/33         Not Match   2/33
4        SP  2/17             Match   2/17

result = (df22.set_index('adsl')
              .combine_first(df1.set_index('adsl'))
              .reset_index()
              .reindex(columns=df1.columns))
print (result)
   adsl  svc_no port_stat adsl.1 Comparison result
0  2/17     NaN        SP   2/17             Match
1  2/24     NaN        RE   2/24         Not Match
2  2/27     NaN        SP   2/27             Match
3  2/33     NaN        SP   2/33         Not Match
4  2/37     NaN        SP   2/37         Not Match
5  3/12     NaN       NaN    NaN               NaN
```

Comment: How do you suggest that I would be able to **wb1.xlsx** with the values of **wb2.xlsx*

Comment: @RickyAguilar - I change answer, can you check it?

Comment: Yes. It's like their key.

Comment: @RickyAguilar - Super, so solution should working nice.

Comment: hmm, the values of `df1` aside from the `adsl` are empty, and after the match of `adsl` from, that would only be the time that the values of `df2` be compied to `df2`. So.. in the `result`, `adsl` and `adsl.1` should be a match.

Comment: The other values are just copied along with its matched `adsl` from `wb2.xlsx` to `wb1.xlsx`

Comment: Can you change data in first `df1` and add expected output?

Comment: Nope. The final format is the `df1`. The other values of empty columns will come from `df2` that matched from `df2['adsl']` to `df1['adsl']`

Comment: @RickyAguilar - It is more clear now for me, but you need rename columns and create new ones if need matching.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking at.

Comment: @RickyAguilar - Thank you for patience :)